# How can I put an Express REST layer on top of an Apollo GraphQL server?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm looking into putting a REST layer (using Express) on top of a GraphQL server (Apollo Server v2) to support some legacy apps. To share as much logic as possible, the REST endpoint should ideally wrap a GraphQL query that I'm sending to the GraphQL server, and be able to do small modifications to the response before sending the response to the client.

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to query the apollo server from the Express routing middleware. So far I've explored two different solutions:

1. Modify the request from the REST endpoint such that `req.body` is a valid graphql query, change the `req.url` to `/graphql`, and call `next()`. The problem with this is that I cannot modify the result before it's being sent to the client, which I need to do.
2. Calling the `/graphql` endpoint with axios from the routing middleware, and modify the response before sending to the client. This works, but feels to me a bit hacky.

Do you have other suggestions, or maybe even an example?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution 2 is okay to implement.

I've made a similar implementation, but in my case, a GraphQL service fetches data from another(multiple) GraphQL service(s).
And somewhere down the line I did something like this:

```
export type serviceConnectionType = {
    endpoint: string
    queryType: {
        query: Object // gql Object Query
        variables: {
            input: Object // query arguments (can be null)
        }
    }
}

export async function connectService(params: serviceConnectionType) {
    const response = await fetch(params.endpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(params.queryType),
    })

    if (response.status === 404) {
        console.warn('404 not found')
    }

    return response.json()
}
```